# fpdf set pdf height and oriention to auto

Tags: php, fpdf

I am adding text to the pdf using fpdf.I am able to add the text but size of pdf page is always A4.
If uploaded pdf orientation is landscape it becomes portrait.
I want to use the same widht and height and orientation of the uploaded pdf for for writting in to the pdf.

```
$fullPathToFile = $target_path;

    class custom_PDF extends FPDI {

    var $_tplIdx;
    var $file;

    function Header() {
        if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {
        // THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE NUMBER OF PAGES
        $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($this->file);
        $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);
        }
        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx, 0, 0, 200);
    }

    function Footer() {

    }

    function setFile($param) {
        $this->file = $param;
    }

    }
    $pdf234 = new custom_PDF();
    $pdf234->setFile($fullPathToFile);
    $pdf234->AddPage();
    $pdf234->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
    $pdf234->SetY(280);
    $pdf234->SetFont("helvetica", "B", 8);
    $pdf234->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);


    $utf8text = $current_user->user_login . "(" . str_ireplace('_', ' ', $current_user->roles[0]) . ")," . get_bloginfo('name') . "," . get_bloginfo('url') . "" . date("d M Y,h:i:s a");
    $pdf234->Write(5, $utf8text, get_bloginfo('url'));
    if ($pdf234->numPages > 1) {
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $pdf234->numPages; $i++) {
        //$pdf->endPage();
        $pdf234->_tplIdx = $pdf234->importPage($i);
        $pdf234->AddPage();
          $pdf234->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
        $pdf234->SetY(280);

        $pdf234->Write(5, $utf8text, get_bloginfo('url'));
    }
    }
    $pdf234->Output($line['name'], 'D');
    die();
```

I have tried the following code too:

```
$specs = $pdf234->getTemplateSize($pdf234->_tplIdx);
 $pdf234->AddPage('L',$specs);
```

my pdf in now in landscape mode but content is not occupying whole page.content is aligned to left top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to detect uploaded pdf dimension.I used getTemplateSize() function to get width and height to create a layout.
Here is my code:

```
    $fullPathToFile = $target_path;

    class custom_PDF extends AlphaPDF {

    var $_tplIdx;
    var $file;

    function Header() {
        if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {
        // THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE NUMBER OF PAGES
        $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($this->file);
        $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);
        }
        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx, 0, 0);
    }

    function Footer() {

    }

    function setFile($param) {
        $this->file = $param;
    }

    function RotatedText($x, $y, $txt, $angle) {
        //Text rotated around its origin
        $this->Rotate($angle, $x, $y);
        $this->Text($x, $y, $txt);
        $this->Rotate(0);
    }

    }

    $pdf234 = new custom_PDF();
    $pdf2345 = new custom_PDF(); //detect size of uploaded pdf
    $pdf234->setFile($fullPathToFile);
    $pdf2345->setFile($fullPathToFile);
    $pdf2345->AddPage();
    $specs = $pdf2345->getTemplateSize($pdf2345->_tplIdx);
    if ($specs['w'] > $specs['h']) {
    $pdf234->AddPage('L', array($specs['w'], $specs['h']));
    } else {
    $pdf234->AddPage();
    }
    $pdf234->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
    $pdf234->SetAlpha(0.7);
    $pdf234->SetFont('courier', '', 10);
    $pdf234->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    $pdf234->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $utf8text1 = $current_user->user_login . "(" . str_ireplace('_', ' ', $current_user->roles[0]) . ")," . get_bloginfo('name') . "," . get_bloginfo('url');
    $utf8text2 = date("d M Y,h:i:s a") . "," . $current_user->data->user_email;
    $pdf234->SetFont('helvetica', '', 13);
    $pdf234->SetTextColor(128, 128, 128);
    if ($specs['w'] > $specs['h']) {

    $pdf234->RotatedText(($specs['w'] / 2) - 50, ($specs['h'] / 2) + 45, $utf8text1, 40);
    $pdf234->RotatedText(($specs['w'] / 2) - 40, ($specs['h'] / 2) + 45, $utf8text2, 40);
    } else {
    $pdf234->RotatedText(45, 180, $utf8text1, 40);
    $pdf234->RotatedText(55, 180, $utf8text2, 40);
    }
    if ($pdf234->numPages > 1) {
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $pdf234->numPages; $i++) {
        //$pdf->endPage();
        $pdf234->_tplIdx = $pdf234->importPage($i);
        $pdf234->AddPage();
        $pdf234->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
        $pdf234->SetY(280);
        $pdf234->SetAlpha(0.7);
        $pdf234->SetFont('helvetica', '', 13);
        $pdf234->SetTextColor(128, 128, 128);
        $pdf234->RotatedText(45, 180, $utf8text1, 40);
        $pdf234->RotatedText(55, 180, $utf8text2, 40);
    }
    }
    $pdf234->Output($line['name'], 'D');
    die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dimensions in the constructor:

```
FPDF([string orientation [, string unit [, mixed size]]])
```

**Example**:

```
$pagesize = array(107, 199);
$pdf234 = new FPDF( 'P', 'mm', $pagesize );
```

**or with:**

```
AddPage([string orientation [, mixed size]]);
```

Example:

```
$pdf234->AddPage('P','A5');
```

**Description**

Adds a new page to the document.

***Parameters***

**orientation**

Page orientation. Possible values are (case insensitive):

- P or Portrait
- L or Landscape

The default value is the one passed to the constructor.

**size**

Page size. It can be either one of the following values (case insensitive):

- A3
- A4
- A5
- Letter
- Legal

or an array containing the width and the height (expressed in user unit).

The default value is the one passed to the constructor.

Comment: `$specs = $pdf234->getTemplateSize($pdf234->_tplIdx);
$pdf234->AddPage('L',$specs);`

my pdf in now in landscape mode but content is not occupying whole page.content is aligned to left top.